# How to check if all of the elements in an array are the same, in matlab?

Tags: matlab

There must be a simple matlab way of doing this.  I have a row vector and I want to check if all of the elements are equal.  Brute forcing this in a loop is easy, but looking for a more efficient approach :)  The elements are integers

Comment: how big is the matrix?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I think it can be as simple as

```
if all(v == v(1))
```

Another method would be

```
if range(v) == 0
```

Comment: @reve_etrange - because you misunderstand the question. isequal tests to see if TWO arrays are identical. Please re-read the question as asked. It asks if all elements of a SINGLE array are equal to each other.

Comment: Where is the function range located? Is it a toolbox function?

Comment: @Andrey: Statistics toolbox, apparently

Comment: Note that both these methods only work for 1-dimensional arrays (as the question requested). To modify this to work on any size array, simply call `if all(v(:)==v(1))`.

Comment: Also worth noting that the two suggested approaches will give different results for arrays containing NaN values 
>> all([3 NaN 3]==3)
ans = 0

>> range([3 NaN 3])==0
ans = 1

Comment: Would any(v ~= v(1)) be faster? It may only need to check until it finds the first true case... although I am not sure if matlab actually works in this sequential way.

Comment: @Giuseppe: `all` only needs to check until it finds the first false case.  There's no advantage to inverting the test.

Answer (score 11):

How about: `max(v) == min(v)`? :-)

Comment: This would work, but I expect that it is slower than the accepted solution.

Comment: @m7913d I checked it. This answer is as fast as the top one.

Answer (score 10):

Another solution:

```
numel(unique(v))==1
```

Comment: @Alex: For incorrect in theory but useful in practice useful values of "works".

Answer (score 3):

Another solution:

```
sum(abs(diff(v))) == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need the `all` in the solution above, just `if v == v(1)`.

Comment: The `all` is needed if you try to make logic combinations (`&&` and `||`) between this condition and other boolean expressions.