# Recognise that numbers in a row of a matrix are all the same number

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix of `0`s, `1`s, `2`s and `3`s.If all the elements in the same row are the same then I want it to display the text `'flush'`. For example, I have the matrix

```
[0,1,0,2,3; 
 0,0,0,0,0; 
 3,2,1,3,1; 
 2,2,2,2,2];
```

How would I program Matlab to recognise the 2nd and 4th row all have the same number?

Comment: for example when row = 2, use `all(foo(2,1)==foo(2,:))`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if all of the elements in an array are the same, in matlab?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291488/how-to-check-if-all-of-the-elements-in-an-array-are-the-same-in-matlab)

Comment: Or the other way, `all(~(foo(2,:)-foo(2,1)))` ;)

Comment: Perhaps I should have explained better, My matrix is extremely large - 1000x5 I have numbers randomly generated between 0 and 3 to fill the matrix If all the numbers in a row are the same, e.g. [0,0,0,0,0]

[1,1,1,1,1]

 [2,2,2,2,2 ]

[3,3,3,3,3 ]

Then i need to display the word 'flush'

Comment: Hmmm. This might seem like a funny one, but I think you could just use Matlab's built-in Var (variance) function. If the variance of a row is 0, then all of its elements are 0. The code should look really simple, something like out = var(X.').'  and find where out == 0 should give you the index of rows with 0 variance

Comment: @GameOfThrows good idea. It's probably a typo but if the variance is 0 then all the elements are the same, not necessarily 0 :).

Comment: @Benoit_11 oh yeah... too late to change it :( long day today.

Comment: Another way (based on [H.Muster](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10298735/1011724)'s solution) is `sum(abs(diff(A')))==0`

Answer (score 1):

`A = [0,1,0,2,3; 0,0,0,0,0; 3,2,1,3,1; 2,2,2,2,2]`

As it was said before if you only have positive numbers you can use the variance.

`n_flush = var(A, [], 2) == 0`

However, this will fail for negative numbers for example a row like [-2 -1 1 2].

What I would do is to compare the first column with the rest and flag the rows where all the elements are equal.

`n_flush = all(bsxfun(@eq, A(:,1), A(:,2:end)),2)`

Now, if you want to display flush every time the rows are equal you can do

```
for ind = find(n_flush)
   fprintf('flush row %i\n', ind)
end
```

Comment: Why would `[-2 -1 1 2]` be a problem for variance?

Comment: Not clear: why would it be a problem with negative numbers?

Comment: What's the problem with using negative numbers for `var`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to have the whole thing in a one-liner (which is what many Matlab-geeks try to do), then maybe this here will suit your needs

```
cellfun(@(x) char((x==0)*sprintf('flush')), num2cell(var(A')'), 'UniformOutput', false)
```

Edit: nice idea GameOfThrows

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution by explicitly subtracting the first column from each column via duplicating the first column to other columns of a matching-sized matrix.

```
identical_rows = ~any(A - kron(ones(1,size(A,2)),A(:,1)),2)
```