# How to check whether a vector with floating numbers is constant or not (in Matlab)?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vector, floating-point, comparison

A function to check whether a given vector of integer numbers is constant is given in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291488/how-to-check-if-all-of-the-elements-in-an-array-are-the-same-in-matlab). My question is how you could extend this to the case where the vector contains floating numbers.

> Example 1: vector `A=[1 1 1]`

sum(abs(diff(A)))=0. The vector is constant.

> Example 2: vector `B=[pi, 3.1416, 3.141592653589793]`

In `format short`, we obtain sum(abs(diff(B)))=1.4693e-05. However, we can consider these numbers to be equal within the accuracy of `format short` since they all read 3.1416.

Comment: An idea would be `sum(abs(diff(A)))<(n-1)*eps` with _A_ a vector with _n_ elements and _eps_ the smallest representable number (1e-4 for `format short`), but this is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can check like this:

```
if norm(diff(v)) < err
```

Where `v` is the vector to test and `err` is the minimum acceptable error.
If you wanted to test if it was accurate to `n` decimal places then you could do:

```
if norm(diff(v)) < 1e-n
```

or

```
if range(round(v,n)) == 0
```

or

```
if all(diff(round(v,n)) == 0)
```

To get the same result for `format short` we would want to check accuracy to 4 decimal places, so `n=4`.

Comment: * _...<err_ is correct but some cases where _...<(n-1)err_ are excluded


* _...<(n-1)err_ would be incorrect when (the number of differences between consecutive elements that are _>err_) is bigger than (the number of differences between consecutive elements that are _<err_).

Maybe one should check for each difference between consecutive elements whether it is _<eps_.

Comment: @MWijnand You should edit your question to include some examples of how it could be tested and perhaps some larger example vectors which show what you have described here.

Answer (score 0):

If you just round the numbers in the vector to the 4th decimal, you can circumvent the discribed problem:

`B=[pi, 3.1416, 3.141592653589793]
B=round(B*10000)/10000
sum(abs(diff(B)))`

The last expression will return 0.

Comment: You should mark my answer as correct instead of posting a new answer that is the same (if not more convoluted). The `round` function has a second input you can utilise.